# Pass compositeView option to itemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a compositeView that has an itemView.  I am passing in a value through the options object into the compositeview on instantiation.  In the compositeView I have the itemview attribute set to the itemview and I am using the itemViewOptions attribute to try and pass in the value from the options passed into the composite view.  Here is the code I have:

CompositeView:

```
myFirstCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: Handlebars.templates["myTemp"],

initialize: function(options){
    //this console statement works as expected options are there
        console.log("myFirstCompositeView.initialize() -> options -> ", options);
    this.eventBus = options.eventBus;
    this.mapModel = options.myModel;            
    //i tried this
        this.itemView : myFirstItemView;
        this.itemViewOptions = this.myModel;
    },
    i also tried this...
    itemView : myFirstItemView
    itemViewOptions = this.myModel;
});
```

Itemview:

```
myFirstItemView = SegmentItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: Handlebars.templates["myothertemp"],
    initialize : function(options){
    //value undefined
        console.log("myFirstItemView .initialize() -> ", options.myModel);
},

});
```

Instantiation of CompositeView:

```
new myFirstCompositeView ({
    myModel : {testval : 777, teststr: "holy cow"},
    collection: model.get("myFirstCollection"),
    eventBus: eventBus
}));
```

Is there anyway to pass the value into the itemView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myFirstCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: Handlebars.templates["myTemp"],
    initialize: function(options){
        this.eventBus = options.eventBus;
        this.mapModel = options.myModel;            
    },
    itemView : myFirstItemView,
    itemViewOptions: function(){
        return {
            myModel: this.myModel
        };
    }
});
```

[From the Marionette documentation:](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-itemviewoptions)

> You can also specify the itemViewOptions as a function, if you need to
>   calculate the values to return at runtime. The model will be passed
>   into the function should you need access to it when calculating
>   itemViewOptions. The function must return an object, and the
>   attributes of the object will be copied to the itemView instance's
>   options.